# Add sleuth trace id to request header

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have a spring boot application having dependency of spring-cloud-starter-sleuth-3.0.3 and spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin-3.0.3.

I have a requirement that i need to pass trace-id to request header while calling API from webclient.

## Demo webClient

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DemoApiClient {

    private final WebClient demoWebClient;
    private final DemoProperties demoProperties;
    private final Tracer tracer;

    public Mono<DemoDetail> retrieveDemoDetail(String demo){

        return demoWebClient
                .get()
                .uri(uriBuilder->uriBuilder
                        .path(demoProperties.getLookupPath())
                        .build(demo))
                .header("trace-id", tracer.currentSpan().context().traceId())
                .accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(DemoDetail.class)
                .doOnError(e -> log.error("Could not find demo", e));
    }    
}
```

tracer.currentSpan() is coming as null , hence NPE is thrown.

As per document, approach is given to add trace-id to header of response
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/3.0.3/reference/html/howto.html#how-to-add-headers-to-the-http-server-response.

However, i need correct approach to add trace-id to request header.

Answer (score 0):

`WebClient` is instrumented, please see the docs: [`WebClient` integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/3.0.3/reference/htmlsingle/#sleuth-http-client-webclient-integration), so tracing information should be propagated out of the box over the wire.

If you want to do this manually (I don't recommend), you need to check what you do "above" this method that prevents the tracing information to be propagated. E.g.: you are switching threads, coming from an imperative context to Reactor, etc. You can work this around by getting the tracing information before the switch and either propagate it (see `Scope`) or inject it into this method.

Also, you are not sending the whole trace context just the traceId so please check the docs and let Sleuth propagate the tracing information for you.

If you are creating a `WebClient` bean, you are not switching threads, or going back and forth between imperative and reactive, and you still don't see the tracing information in your header (propagated by Sleuth), you can try modifying the [instrumentation mechanism](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/3.0.3/reference/htmlsingle/#sleuth-reactor-integration), I recommend using `DECORATE_QUEUES`.

Also, Sleuth 3.1.x is out, you can try upgrading it.